# Replica calculation in statistical mechanics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, image-processing

i am reading ["Statistical physics of spin glasses and information processing an introduction - Nishimori Hidetoshi"](https://neurophys.biomedicale.parisdescartes.fr/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Nishimori-2001-Statistical-Physics-of-Spin-Glasses-and-Information-Processing-An-Introduction.pdf), chapter 6, page 119 on image restoration. I tried to understand what happened here in this passage but i can't fully understand it. We have:

- $\xi_i$, $\sigma_i^\alpha\in\{+1,-1\}$ for $i=1,...,N$ (number of spin) and $\alpha=1,...,n$ number of replicas of the system $\sigma$ we infer
- $\tau_i$ gaussian random variable with mean $\tau_0\xi_i$ and variance $\tau$;
- from a precedent gaussian linearization we get $m_0,m_\alpha\sim Normal(0,1)$ with $\alpha=1,...,n$.
- $ \beta_s, \beta_m,h$ are parameters. $Tr_\xi$ is the sum over all the configurations of $\{\xi_i\}$, $Tr_\sigma$ over the configurations of the $n$ replicas  $\{\sigma_i^1,...,\sigma_i^n|i=1,..,N\}$
- $\prod d\tau_i$ indicates the multiple integral over all the N variables $\tau_i$ (same for $\prod m_\alpha$)

[image]

The author skips many calculations to get from the 1st to the 2nd expression, here there is my attempt: first i make the substitution $\tau_i=\tau_0\xi_i+\tau u$ with $u \sim N(0,1)$ and explicitate $\sum_i$ when possibile, so we get from the first expression in the screenshot:

$=\frac{\sqrt{N\beta_s(N\beta_m)^n} \cdot \tau^N}{((2\pi\tau)^N*Z(\beta_s)}
\int{\prod_i du \int dm_0 \int \prod_\alpha dm_\alpha \sum_\xi \sum_\sigma}
exp\{-\frac{1}{2\tau^2}(2N\tau_0^2 +2\tau_0\tau u\sum_i \xi_i + N\tau^2u^2)+\frac{\tau_0^2N}{\tau^2}+\frac{u\tau_0\sum_i\xi_i}{\tau}+\tau_0h\cdot\cdot\sum_\alpha \sigma_i^\alpha\sum_i\xi_i+\tau hu\sum_i\sum_\alpha\sigma_i^\alpha\}exp\{\frac{-\beta_s-\beta_sNm_0^2}{2}+\beta_s m_0 \sum_i \xi_i -n\beta_m /2-N\beta_m \sum_\alpha m_\alpha^2+\beta_m\sum_\alpha m_\alpha \sum_i \sigma_i^\alpha \}$

We can cut 1st and 2nd terms in the exponential with 4th and 5th and the $\tau^N$ out of the integral. We can then separate the terms without $\sum_i$ with the terms that contains it and transform the  $exp(\sum_i...)$ into $\prod_i exp(...)$. I get rid of the constant terms and finally I write the N integrals $\int \prod_i du \frac{exp(-\frac{Nu^2}{2})}{\sqrt{2\pi}^N}=\int D_u$ (or at least that's what i think happened here, correct me if that makes no sense, I think that $Du$ is the joint measure of all the N (indipendent) $du$):

$\propto \frac{\sqrt{N\beta_s(N\beta_m)^n}}{Z(\beta_s)}\int dm_0\int \prod_\alpha dm_\alpha$ $e^{\frac{-N\beta_sm_0^2-N\beta_m\sum_\alpha m_\alpha^2}{2})}\prod_i \sum_{\xi,\sigma}e^{(\beta_s m_0 \xi_i+\beta_m\sum_\alpha \sigma_i^\alpha m_\alpha)}\int Du$ $ e^{\tau_0h\xi_i \sum_\alpha \sigma_i^\alpha + \tau h u \sum_\alpha \sigma_i^\alpha)}$

Now, and that's the part I'm most unsure, i think that the system is considered symmetric in $i$ and then we simply call $\xi_i=\xi \in \{+1,-1\}$ and $\sigma_i^\alpha=\sigma^\alpha \in \{1,-1\}$, so that we can eliminate the index $i$ and consider the productory in $i=1,..,N$ as the factor elevated to $N$.

Does this make sense? Considering that in the infinite range the priors are the following then it should be make sense that the system is permutation invariant (in $i$) and then that we can replace the indexing in $i$ with a mute variable, but i'm still not sure.

[image]

If this make sense then we can easily get to the final form:

$=\frac{\sqrt{N\beta_s(N\beta_m)^n}}{Z(\beta_s)}\int dm_0\int \prod_\alpha dm_\alpha exp\{N(\beta_sm_0^2-\beta_m\sum_\alpha m_\alpha^2) + log \sum_{\xi,\sigma^\alpha}\int Du$ $ e^{\beta_s m_0 \xi + \beta_m \sum_\alpha \sigma^\alpha m_\alpha + \tau_0h\xi\sum_\alpha \sigma^\alpha + \tau hu\sum_\alpha \sigma^\alpha}\}$

This is exactly the final form that Nishimori gets in the chapter 6, except for the terms outside the integral (maybe they go away when i do $\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \lim_{n \to 0}${result above}? don't know this either).

Thanks in advance if anybody can help me